# How to create a file and parent directories in one command?

Tags: command-line, directory, directory-structure, mkdir, touch

Is there a flag/option for `touch`, `mkdir`, `>`, or some other command that will allow me to create a file and any non-existent parent directories at the same time?

For instance, let's say I'm in an empty folder. Now I can create parent directories if they don't exist when creating a folder

```
mkdir -p nested/folder
```

I can create files in existing directories

```
touch nested/folder/something.txt
```

But I can't create a file in a directory that doesn't exist yet

```
touch nested/folder/deep/more.txt
```

> touch: cannot touch ‘nested/folder/deep/more.txt’: No such file or directory

How would I create that `deep` folder at the same time I create `more.txt` ?

Comment: Thanks! I came here because I was having a similar issue with `cat` and responses below proved helpful
A little more info about `mkdir -p` http://www.linfo.org/make_directory_tree.html

Answer (score 60):

You can combine the two commands on a single line. If you use a variable you can do this:

```
file="./nested/folder/deep/more.txt"
```

And then this:

```
mkdir -p "${file%/*}" && touch "$file"
```

Or all together on one line like this:

```
mkdir -p "./nested/folder/deep" && touch "./nested/folder/deep/more.txt"
```

It's not one single command but it might do the job for you.

Comment: I recommend `dirname ${file}` instead of cryptic `${file%/*}`

Comment: The question got to something I've been wanting for a long time, but while this answer got me there, it didn't give me exactly what I wanted.  So I wanted to share this function that I just created `mktouch() { mkdir -p $(dirname $1) && touch $1; }`.  I put that in my `.bash_profile` and now I can do `mktouch dir/path/file.ext` and it creates the directory and touches in one command

Comment: @BrianUnderwood probably a good idea to wrap things in quotes: `mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1"`

Comment: Fixed in in my `.bash_profile`, thanks!

Comment: @mwfearnley How to properly wrap commands in nested quotes in `"$(dirname "$1")"`.  I tried your command but it created weird directories and didn't touch any files. Then I tried using single quote outside, and then tried single quote inside, and also tried backticks. Currently I have only wrapped $1 in quotes and kept dirname command itself without quotes. I should also disclose that i am using `$@` instead of `$1` to accept multiple parameters.

Comment: mkdir -p parent/child && touch $_/file.txt

Comment: I hate when I see this... "How do I do X in one command?"  "Oh, it's simple.  Just do two commands and join them on one line". And it's like... no... they clearly want "One Command"

Comment: Actually, this answer contains 2 cmds put together in one line. I think this is not the answer the questioner wants!

Comment: `dirname` calls an external program, `${file%/*}` uses shell builtins, hence is more resource efficient.